# Нужна ли запятая после "Ирви"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп

За ним итарк, Ирви и последним шагал Келан с маленьким топориком за плечами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем? Все они объединены общим действием - шаганием. Иное не подразумевается. (Даже если итарк и Ирви глазели по сторонам.)